# Update Additional Field on Realm Object with ObservedRealmObject in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, realm, combine

*Xcode 12.5, iOS 14.5, macOS 11.3*

Let's say I have a simple Realm class like this in a SwiftUI app:

```
class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
  @objc dynamic var id = ""
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
}
```

I pass an object into a view using `@ObservedRealmObject` where I can edit its `name` property by binding it to a `TextField` view like this:

```
struct DetailView: View {
  @ObservedRealmObject var item: Item

  var body: some View{
  
    TextField("Name...", $item.name)

  }
}
```

When I edit the field, the `name` property updates as I type and the realm is updated in real-time.

But I also want to update the `updated` property with a new `Date()` timestamp whenever the object is modified. Since the write transaction is managed automatically by `@ObservedRealmObject`, I'm unclear on how to pull this off.

How can I change `updated` every time the `name` (or any other additional property) is changed?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer but it sounds like the `updated` var is a more of a computed property - meaning it is altered based on actions on other properties. I assume you have a second view controller with perhaps a 'save' button? If so you could update the property on save. Or, you could add an observer to the object that fires whenever the property is changed and update it there. You could use Swift objects backed by the Realm properties to do that via a computed property. Realm objects are KVO so you could use some old-style KVO magic to update that as well.

Comment: Have you tried using a `didSet` observer on `name`? E.g. `@objc dynamic var name = "" { didSet { updated = Date() } }`

Comment: @robmayoff I don't believe that will work. Realm objects and properties are Objc - note the `@objc dynamic` for each one. willSet/didSet are lightweight (Swift) Property Observers which are independent of KVO, which is what is needed on Realm Objects.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, thank you. I think @Jay's suggestion of just manually setting `updated` on the "save" action of my form is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways this can be accomplished; from simply updating the updated property when the 'save' button is pressed to using KVO to observe changes to the objects name property to adding a Swift 'front end' to the objects objc properties that can be handled through [Computed Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259).

Let's use the third option using Swift Computed Properties and modify the Item in the question.

```
class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
    @objc dynamic var _id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc private dynamic var _name = ""
    @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
    
    var name: String {
        get {
            return _name
        }
        set {
            _name = newValue
            updated = Date()
        }
    }
    
    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

A few things to note:

The realm `name` property was made private with a name change to `_name`. I did that so you don't accidentally set it and go around the Swift implementation.

We then added a new Swift `name` property that acts as the 'front end' property to a Realm property backed by `_name`.

When an item is created using the convenience function `let i = Item(name: "Item 0")` or set within a write block `someItem.name = "Updated name"` the `name` computed property sets the Realm property and also populates the `updated` property

```
set {
   _name = newValue
   updated = Date()
}
```

This *should* work seamlessly with `@ObservedRealmObject`